# Overriding parents' color does not work

Tags: javascript, nvd3.js

I am trying to set color of text node in `nvd3` but it is not working because parent `g` node overrides it somehow. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
    g.append("text")
        .attr("x", center[0])
        .attr("y", center[1])
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .style("fill", "white")
        .text(key);
```

So, the `.style("fill", "white")` is not working.

Here is how the `DOM` looks like:

[image]

`Text` node is appended (as a child of the last `g`, I am just not showing it since it is way below), I see it with the right `fill` property, but the color of the appended `text` is still `rgb(44, 123, 182)`.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try adding `white !important`

Comment: Tried, not working

Comment: Are there any other `fill` attributes in _all_ that syntax that is between what is shown and the text?

Comment: None. Just to test I isolated the code in a function and put it in different places. When the program is running it is not even blinking a single time.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to just append the text nodes to the parent of the `nv-group` element that was determining the color and it started to work. If anyone knows how to actually override the color, please, share the answer.

Comment: (1) have you tried .attr("fill", "white") instead of .style ?   or  (2) .style('fill', 'white ')  --Note the single quotes